# bootstrap modal is diplayed locally but not online

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

A bootstrap modal in one of my sites is working perfect when i view it localy (the PDF is loading fine) but online although the modal is working the PDF is not diplayed.

Any ideas?

Thank you

```html
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    <i class="fa fa-download"></i>Launch my CV
                   </button> 


                   <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">CV</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <embed id="modalembed" src="img/cv.pdf" data-backdrop="static"  data-keyboard="false">
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: That's because your PDF file can't be found.

Comment: but it is online on the img folder